# How can i resolve this issue: ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: postgresql-client (missing): required by: world[postgresql-client]?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

Please, can someone help me?
I just started learning Django-REST-API using Docker. I want to install postgresql-11-alpine but i keep getting this error messages when i run; `docker-compose build:`

WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: temporary error (try again later)
WARNING: Ignoring http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz: temporary error (try again later)
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
postgresql-client (missing):
required by: world[postgresql-client]
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client' returned a non-zero code: 1

Below is my `Dockerfile` file

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
MAINTAINER Tboost Technology
#set environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
    gcc libc-dev python3-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

#mkdir to store your apps source code
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

#create user to run apps in the docker
RUN adduser -D user
#switch to the user
USER user
```

Below is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: "3"

services: 
    app:
        build: 
            context: .
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
        extra_hosts: 
            - "host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1"
        volumes: 
            - ./app:/app
        command: >
            sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        environment: 
            - DB_HOST=db
            - DB_NAME=app
            - DB_USER=postgres
            - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
        depends_on: 
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:11-alpine
        restart: always
        environment: 
            - POSTGRES_DB=app
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
```

My `requirements.txt` file:

```
Django>=3.0.7,<3.0.8
djangorestframework>=3.11.0,<3.12.0
psycopg2>=2.7.5,<2.8.0

flake8>=3.6.0,<3.7.0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and was able to solve it by:

1. Installing the postgresql-client, I used the link below

   [Create a Postgresql Docker Container](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/create-a-postgresql-docker-container-975)

2. Restart the docker service: `sudo systemctl restart docker`
3. Run the docker compose build command: `docker-compose build`

Comment: OP's problem involves alpine container and the link you provided provides snippets for `apt` package manager

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was issue of network. Container did not have access to internet.

It was solved by running a command:

```
docker build --network=host . -t recipe_app_api
```

and using *recipe_app_api* image inside docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using `ruby:2.6.1-alpine`, this alpine version is `3.9` which is does not support `postgresql-client14`, please check your versions of OS and client